# replace multiple queries with a single query which will give the same result

Tags: sql, postgresql

**The queries are :**

```
select date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 month' as prev_month_first_date 
select (date_trunc('month', now())::date-1 - interval '0 days') as prev_month_last_date;
select date_trunc('month', now()) as current_month_first_date;
SELECT date_trunc('year', now()) as current_year_first_date;
SELECT date_trunc('quarter', now()) as current_quarter_first_date;
```

can I form a single query with all these queries? I am working on postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for separate columns, just use a single `select` with multiple expressions:

```
select date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 month' as prev_month_first_date,
      (date_trunc('month', now())::date-1 - interval '0 days') as prev_month_last_date,
      date_trunc('month', now()) as current_month_first_date,
      date_trunc('year', now()) as current_year_first_date,
      date_trunc('quarter', now()) as current_quarter_first_date;
```